# How can I specify with OpenAPI/Swagger™ a resource that's found at URL supplied by the server?

Tags: openapi, hateoas

Consider HTML. You write a tag `<img src="http://example.com/image.png"/>` and the browser retrieves the image at the location specified. I'm designing my API to use a similar mechanism where it's up to the server where any secondary resources and it supplies the location of those resources in the form of a URL.

I'm writing an OpenAPI document to describe all the JSON structures that are sent up to and returned by the server. It works great except I don't know how to express the relationship between the URL inside the response to the first resource to the second resource.

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Minimal Spec for Question.
  version: 0.0.0
paths:
  /firstRefToSecond:
    get:
      description: Gets some data including a reference to a secondary resource. 
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  RefToSecond:
                    type: string
                    description: The URL to the second resource.
                    example: "http://example.org/second"
  /secondResourceExampleUrlNotActuallyThisUrl:
    get:
      description: 
        The second resource. 
        Found at the URL pointed to by RefToSecond.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  Data:
                    type: integer
                    description: The data.
                    example: 12
```

Here, the second "path" is simply a placeholder for the second URL. I would prefer not to have that placeholder at all and instead substitute the path for wherever that URL points.

Is there a way in OpenAPI to express this relationship between the "refToSecond" URL property and the requirements of what that secondary interaction would look like, without linking it to an explicit URL set in advance?

Comment: I'm curious why you need Swagger/OpenAPI documentation if you want to use HATEOAS according to your tags. The latter one already allows to navigate using the returned response and teaches how to make further requests through affordances and form-based representations. I'm not sure how the former one will improve that design. Furthermore, it is the media types job to define and explain the elements that may appear within a document and how clients should operate on it. Swagger/OpenAPI is the wrong tooling therefore IMO

Comment: @RomanVottner - OpenAPI has a very nice language for specifying how to build the JSON packages that are exchanged between client and service. I've got a section for "GET /" and the response (HATEOAS style) will include a set of URLs that the client may interact with, which I've specified how elsewhere in the OpenAPI YAML. That last link in the chain is the only bit I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in OpenAPI to express this relationship between the "refToSecond" URL property and the requirements of what that secondary interaction would look like, without linking it to an explicit URL set in advance?

It is possible to formally express a relationship between the response of an operation and another request URL: See the [Link feature](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/). The section "Runtime Expression Syntax" is apparently helpful for your case. (Disclaimer: I have never seen this feature being used anywhere in practice so far.)

But this only allows to express the relation to the operation that is available at the server-defined URL. You cannot specify dynamic endpoints in OpenAPI, so you cannot provide a detailed description of the request and response (except in the way you showed in the question).